# How can I combine 2 PDA's into 1 PDA deterministically?

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have two PDAs one with $\{a^i b^j \mid i > j\}$ and the other $\{a^i b^j \mid i < j\}$.

I know how to combine these two PDAs non-deterministically. My question is how do I combine these two PDAs into one *deterministic* PDA? What's the process and could I get a visual example of how to do it?

Comment: By combine, do you mean you want a deterministic PDA that accepts $\{a^i b^j | i > j\} \cup \{a^i b^j | i < j\} = \{a^i b^j | i \not= j\}$?

Answer (score 2):

The family of deterministic context-free languages is not closed under union. For example, as vonbrand mentions in a comment to [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/120424/683), the languages $\{a^nb^n : n \in \mathbb N\}$ and $\{a^nb^{2n} : n \in \mathbb N\}$ are both deterministic context-free, but their union is not.

What this means is that there is no general way to take two deterministic PDAs and to combine them into a deterministic PDA which accepts the union of the languages accepted by the constituent PDAs.